# Python: Transform or Melt and Groupby a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have something like this:

```
df =
       col1  col2  col3
    0     B     C     A
    1     E     D     G
    2   NaN     F     B
```

EDIT : I need to convert it into this:

```
result =
           Name    location  
        0     B   col1,col2
        1     C        col1     
        2     A        col1
        3     E        col2     
        4     D        col2        
        5     G        col2     
        6     F        col3
```

Essentially getting a "location" telling me which column an "Name" is in. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your expected output. B should have ```col1,col3```  not ```col1,col2```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or an alternative with `stack()`:

```
new = df.stack().reset_index().drop('level_0',axis=1).dropna()
new.columns = ['name','location']
```

prints:

```
   name location
0  col1        B
1  col2        C
2  col3        A
3  col1        E
4  col2        D
5  col3        G
6  col2        F
```

**EDIT:**

To get your updated output you could use a `groupby` along with `join()`:

```
new.groupby('location').agg({'name':lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))}).reset_index()
```

Which gives you:

```
 location        name
0        A        col3
1        B  col1, col3
2        C        col2
3        D        col2
4        E        col1
5        F        col2
6        G        col3
```

Comment: @Yash can you provide an example (input/output)?

Answer (score 2):

Try `melt` and `dropna`:

```
>>> df.melt(var_name='location').dropna().groupby('value', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
  value    location
0     B  col1, col3
1     E        col1
2     C        col2
3     D        col2
4     F        col2
5     A        col3
6     G        col3
>>>
```

Also `groupby` and `agg`.

Comment: i updated the question, do you know of an easy way to do that? Thank you again.

Comment: @Yash Added a much better solution, also keeps the order.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `melt` to convert `columns` to `rows`. And give the `rows` a `column` name.

Then `dropna` to remove the `NaN` values in `rows`.

```
df = df.melt(var_name="location", value_name="Name").dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.melt` and `pandas.groupby.agg`:

```
df = df.melt(var_name="location", value_name="Name").dropna()
new_df = df.groupby("Name", as_index=False).agg(",".join)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Name   location
0    A       col3
1    B  col1,col3
2    C       col2
3    D       col2
4    E       col1
5    F       col2
6    G       col3
```